# Verb form of "ridden"

Tags: verbs, past-participles

I see the word "ridden" used in the following ways:

In this case, it seems synonymous with "Being full of":

> **Ridden** with guilt, the man killed himself

In the following passage from "The Thing on the Doorstep" by H.P. Lovecraft, it forms an adjective with a noun:

> I will not change souls with that bullet-**ridden** lich in the madhouse!

I would like to use it as a verb in the following way:

> “Not so invisible now, are you?” I laughed as bloody gashes ____ the invisible man.

Of course, words such as "covered" works just fine, but I was just curious if there is a way to use a form of "ridden" for this situation. I know the past-participle of "ride" is "ridden", but it does not seem appropriate for this situation.

Comment: You could use the verb *riddled*, which is arguably the [word](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/riddle) that should be used instead of *ridden* in *"bullet-ridden"*. [See blog entry](http://throwgrammarfromthetrain.blogspot.com/2013/06/riddle-me-this-bullet-ridden-corpse.html).

Comment: _Ridden_ in this sense is simply a specialised use of the past participle of _ride_, so the verb would have to be _ride_. That doesn't work, though, so you're left with no other option but to choose a different verb like _cover_ or _riddle_.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bullet+riddled%2Cbullet+ridden%2Criddled+with+bullets%2Cridden+with+bullets&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbullet%20riddled%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbullet%20ridden%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Criddled%20with%20bullets%3B%2Cc0

Comment: *bed-ridden* is no doubt from *ride*. *bullet-ridden* is probably from *riddled* with bullets (or bullet holes).

Answer (score 1):

*To ride* means to support or carry, and from the equestrian sense, the past participle has the meaning of being forced or required to carry and to be under the control of the rider. This has led to the combination *X-ridden*, which means to carry the burden of X and to be controlled by it. The *OED* attests to *priest-ridden* from 1653, meaning to be "held in subjection by priestly authority".

The transposition to *riddled with X*, for X equal to *guilt*, is much less popular in both the Ngram viewer and the straight google, but it does have some currency. From [*Passion and Reason: Making Sense of Our Emotions*](https://books.google.com/books?id=FY3-eRwyxtwC&pg=PA64&dq=%22ridden%20with%20guilt%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwieyqyf7oDQAhWESiYKHQmRB5gQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=ridden%20with%20guilt&f=false) by Richard S. Lazarus and Bernice N. Lazarus:

> [I]t is one thing to feel guilt for a particular moral lapse, but it is another thing to be **ridden with guilt** because we feel our very charactert as an individual is unworthy.

It seems unlikely that a lich (one of the undead) would carry and be controlled by bullets. More likely the lich was shot through, or as the commenters above suggest, *riddled*.

Answer (score 1):

*Ridden* in *guilt-ridden* is as you note the past participle of *ride*, including in this sense; it figuratively suggest that the guilt is controlling them as a rider controls a horse and perhaps originally first used in *hag-ridden* which at first could mean one was literally believed to be ridden by a witch at night.

*Bullet-ridden* is found outside of just that one Lovecraft quote, but not a lot and as Peter suggests, it likely was a malapropism for *riddled*.

*Riddle* means covered in holes and so cannot be as well-used for *gashes* as bullet-holes (or even other types of stabbing).

As such your original *covered* seems the better choice. Otherwise, a fresher figurative use might serve ("his skin was completely tattooed with gashes", "his naked body seemed clothed in blood and gashes", "he was a mess of gashes", "his body was nothing but gashes").

Comment: I am a trifle sceptical of this, though it is compatible with the OED's position. The OED provides a single etymology - *the past participle of ride* across many senses including those which involve horses. It does not adequately explain things like *guilt ridden*. If *ridden* means "controlled by", why do we say *ridden with guilt*, *ridden with dirt* etc. Why the preposition *with* and not *by*? Used in this sense *ridden* means *beset with*, *infested with* etc. I don't really see how this (OED sense 3) could be implied by *ride*.

Comment: I believe the *riddled* connection is closer - see OED *riddled* - adj. sense 2b. *As the second element in compounds: filled with holes by the thing specified; full of or afflicted with the thing specified*. Most recent example
*2005   Arena May 22/4   The derision I pour upon my lactose-intolerant, allergy-riddled demi-vegetarian co-workers.* Though how *riddled* - meaning "with many holes" got to mean "infested with/beset with" is puzzling - perhaps, as you suggest, only by malapropism.